# Sum of Sumif Over Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I know Im not doing this properly but I am a VBA beginner and am trying to perform a sumif of a value on multiple sheets in a workbook and then return a sum of those sumifs.

This is how I tried but I get a #NAME? error and don't know where to go from here.

```
Public Function Lookup(x As Long) As Long

Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, arr() As Variant

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Purchased.xlsm")

For Each sh In wb
    arr() = Application.SumIf(Range("A1:A10000"), x, Range("B1:B10000"))
Next

Lookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr())

End Function
```

I have been unable to get this working and it returns a #VALUE! error but I think this may be closer to what I need:

```
Public Function AddItUp(x As Long) As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, RunningSum() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Week1Input.xlsm")
j = wb.Worksheets.Count
ReDim RunningSum(1 To j)
For i = 1 To j
    RunningSum(i) = Application.SumIf(wb.sh(i).Range("A1:A10"), x, wb.sh(i).Range("B1:B10"))
Next i
AddItUp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RunningSum)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just combining the workbooks because this was the only way I could get it to work:

```
Public Function AddItUp(x As Long) As Long
Dim RunningSum() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
j = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ReDim RunningSum(3 To j)
For i = 3 To j
    RunningSum(i) = Application.SumIf(Worksheets(i).Range("A1:A10000"), x, Worksheets(i).Range("B1:B10000"))
Next i
AddItUp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RunningSum)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't assign a value to an empty array. change the `arr()` to something that can hold the value. Also, Lookup is a built in function name in excel, and it's confusing to excel (and other users)

```
Public Function AddItUp(x As Long) As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, RunningSum As Variant
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Purchased.xlsm")
RunningSum=0
For Each sh In wb
    RunningSum = RunningSum + _
        Application.SumIf(Range("A1:A10000"), x, Range("B1:B10000"))
    'line broken for readability
Next
AddItUp = RunningSum
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in a better direction!! So, I used Lookup to shorten what I had, thanks for the pointer. When I use this code I get a #VALUE! error. I have tried making sure that the formats are all correct and that everything looks good, but still get the error. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: I have done more working on this to find that the RunningSum = RunningSum + Application.... does not work to store the values from each sheet as it loops through. Is there a solution to storing the outputs from a For loop and summing them?

Comment: looking again at the function, you may need to use `SumIf(sh.Range("A1:A10000"), x, sh.Range("B1:B10000"))` to ensure excel knows what range to look at

Comment: I am still getting a #VALUE! error. I came up with another idea but it doesn't work either. I will post it above.